# Section of a separated morphism is closed immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is about this page https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KH

Assume $f:X\to S$ have a section $s$.

In lemma 26.21.11., they claim the morphism $S\to S\times_SX$ is $s$, but this comes from upper arrow in the fibered diagram in lemma 26.21.9. However, I got a bit lost in chasing the diagram to see it is really $s$. Is there a clear way to see?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can see that this map:  $S→S×_SX$ is indeed $s:S→X$ by considering the universal property of the fibre product.

You can see that $(X, id_X:X→X, f:X→S)$ satisfies the universal property of the aforementioned fibre product and the morphism $→×_$ is the one induced by the two morphisms $s:S→X$ and $id_S:S→S$ .
After that what you want follows immediately .

Hope this helps!